# Is it possible to create a custom miniconda/anaconda like installer for linux

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, miniconda

It is normally possible to install miniconda on a remote server and run a command like

```
 conda install -c pandas bottleneck
```

However, there are two things that are unfavorable to this. I need to install roughly 20 packages on many remote servers. Even when running these commands I get a `CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/pandas/linux-64/repodata.json>`
 because of the remote locations have limited internet access I assume.

So I was wondering how I could set up a sh file to install a version of miniconda with all the packages needed (lightweight version of anaconda) that I can rsync to other servers. Similar to how you run `bash Latest-Version-anaconda3-x86_64.sh` which installs python and packages.

Let me know if clarification is needed.

Edit: I should add that anaconda does have all the needed packages but to rsync the installer onto these servers takes in excess of a hour

Comment: Conda is fully self contained, e.g. all you need is inside the "anaconda" folder. You could just copy it. Is that OK?

Comment: @JonasAdler The conda folder could be copied actuall, yeah. The file size is larger than the installer though. I guess compressing should work. I'll give that a shot thanks.

Comment: Did it work out well?

Comment: @JonasAdler It works, I'm trying to decide if this is how I want to do it moving forward. It took about 1 hour moving the file overnight through a crontab. I could set up to do 3 or 4 a night for a week. I used tar to compress the file but it didn't seem to change the size to much I might try a different compression method.

Comment: @JonasAdler the file size for the compressed miniconda size ends up being larger than the .sh file installer for anaconda. I think for the meantime I will just rsync the anaconda installer untill I find a better alternative. I'm getting problems with the code running as well with the miniconda install. I think due to a problem with the file transfer or compression.